# How to section a date period monthly

Tags: php, datetime

two dates `13-10-2017` and `13-02-2018`. I want to separate this period in months like `13-10-2017 to 31-10-2-17`, `01-11-2017 to 30-11-2017`, `01-12-2017 to 31-12-2017`, `01-01-2018 to 31-01-2018` and `01-02-2018 to 13-02-2018`. What I did I can get the month names in the date period but not in the format I want.

Here is my code:

```
$start_date = new DateTime('13-10-2017');
$end_date = new DateTime('13-02-2018');
$date_interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$date_period   = new DatePeriod($start_date, $date_interval, $end_date);
# calculating number of days in the interval
$interval  = $start_date->diff( $end_date );
$days = $interval->days;
# getting names of the months in the interval
$month_count = 0;
$month_names = array();
foreach ($date_period as $date) {
    $month_names[] = $date->format('F');
    $month_count++;
}
$month_name_string = implode(',', $month_names);
echo $start_date->format('d-m-Y').' to '.$end_date->format('d-m-Y'). ' is ' .$days.' days and month names are: '.$month_name_string;
```

The output I get :

`13-10-2017 to 13-02-2018 is 123 days and month names are: October,November,December,January`

Comment: can you print the result you have got?

Comment: Yes. here is the output `13-10-2017 to 13-02-2018 is 123 days and month names are: October,November,December,January` @Hassan

Comment: what the output you are expecting ? @MofiqulIslam

Comment: @Mofiqul Islam Put this as an edit to your question, not just a comment.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about what your wanting to happen and in what format?

Comment: I want output as date periods for single month in (multiple section of the input date period) like `13-10-2017 to 31-10-2-17, 01-11-2017 to 30-11-2017, 01-12-2017 to 31-12-2017, 01-01-2018 to 31-01-2018 and 01-02-2018 to 13-02-2018` @Hassan

Comment: @MofiqulIslam, what about month names?

Comment: ah I got it, yalla give me some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, while iterating, do the following checks:

- If the current month is in `$start_date`, use its day for the start date
- If the current month is in `$end_date`, use its day for the last day
- Else, use the 1 and maximum day of each month (using the [`t` format character](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

Also, you need to set the time to 00:00:01 in the final day in order to have it considered in the `DateInterval`:

```
<?php
$start_date = new DateTime('13-10-2017');
$end_date = new DateTime('13-02-2018');
$end_date->setTime(0, 0, 1); // important, to consider the last day!
$date_interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$date_period   = new DatePeriod($start_date, $date_interval, $end_date);
# calculating number of days in the interval
$interval  = $start_date->diff( $end_date );
$days = $interval->days;
# getting names of the months in the interval
$dates = [];
foreach ($date_period as $date) {
    $dateArr = [];
    if ($date->format("Y-m") === $start_date->format("Y-m")) {
        $dateArr["start"] = $start_date->format("d-m-Y");
    }
    else {
        $dateArr["start"] = $date->format("01-m-Y");
    }
    if ($date->format("Y-m") === $end_date->format("Y-m")) {
        $dateArr["end"] = $end_date->format("d-m-Y");
    }
    else {
        $dateArr["end"] = $date->format("t-m-Y"); // last day of the month
    }
    $dates[] = $dateArr;
}
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    echo $date["start"]." to ".$date["end"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qOLHk)

Comment: Works out of the box :)

Comment: Glad I could help. For some reason I had the format as `m-d-Y`, I edited it now to `d-m-Y`, in case it's important for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) function. E.g.:

```
$month_intervals = [];
foreach ($date_period as $date) {
    $start = $date == $start_date ? $start_date : $date->modify('first day of this month');
    $month_intervals[] = join([
        $start->format('d-m-Y'),
        $date->modify('last day of this month')->format('d-m-Y')
    ], ' to ');
}
$month_intervals[] = join([
    (clone $end_date)->modify('first day of this month')->format('d-m-Y'),
    $end_date->format('d-m-Y')
], ' to ');
echo implode(',', $month_intervals);
```

Comment: Works but I am losing the 13 days of Feb month

Comment: Then the `$date_period` doesn't have the last month, and you need to push it to the array after the loop. Updated the answer.